# How to scale central item in SwiftUI ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a carousal such that the central item is larger than the items on the sides. I've added a `scaleEffect` but I can't figure out how to detect & update the items such that the `scaleEffect` takes effect?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    private let images = ["img","img","img","img","img","img"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<images.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        Image(images[index])
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0))
                            .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                            .scaleEffect(currentIndex == index ? 1 : 0.8)
                            .animation(.easeIn, value: currentIndex)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .id(index)
                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .frame(height: 350)
            .padding(.vertical)
            .scrollIndicators(.never)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .safeAreaPadding(.horizontal, 70)
            .safeAreaPadding(.vertical, 10)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the [`scrollTransition`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrolltransition(_:axis:transition:)) modifier to the `Image`:

```
.scrollTransition { content, phase in
    content
        .scaleEffect(phase.isIdentity ? 1 : 0.8)
}
```

Instead of managing your own `currentIndex` state, this modifier gives you a `phase`, and you can decide the scale based on that. It also animates the effect automatically.

By checking `phase == .topLeading`/`phase == .bottomTrailing` separately, you can also have different effects depending on which side of the scroll view the image is at.